# TypeError: vertices is undefined - three.js exporter for Blender

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, export, blender

Having a problem loading the JSON file produced by the [three.js exporter for Blender](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/utils/exporters/blender), that comes with three.js r.86.

Setup done without issues. To test this exporter, I open Blender, and I use the *untitled* Blender file that contains a cube:

[image: Screenshot Blender v2.78]

Exporting it without any adjustments, it produces the following JSON file:

```json
{
    "metadata":{
        "generator":"io_three",
        "normal":36,
        "position":36,
        "version":3,
        "type":"BufferGeometry"
    },
    "data":{
        "index":{
            "array":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35],
            "itemSize":1,
            "type":"Uint16Array"
        },
        "attributes":{
            "normal":{
                "array":[-7.10543e-15,-1,2.98023e-08,-7.10543e-15,-1,2.98023e-08,-7.10543e-15,-1,2.98023e-08,7.10543e-15,1,-2.98023e-08,7.10543e-15,1,-2.98023e-08,7.10543e-15,1,-2.98023e-08,1,-2.38419e-07,7.10543e-15,1,-2.38419e-07,7.10543e-15,1,-2.38419e-07,7.10543e-15,-5.96046e-08,-2.98023e-07,1,-5.96046e-08,-2.98023e-07,1,-5.96046e-08,-2.98023e-07,1,-1,-1.49012e-07,-2.38419e-07,-1,-1.49012e-07,-2.38419e-07,-1,-1.49012e-07,-2.38419e-07,2.38419e-07,1.78814e-07,-1,2.38419e-07,1.78814e-07,-1,2.38419e-07,1.78814e-07,-1,-1.77636e-15,-1,2.98023e-08,-1.77636e-15,-1,2.98023e-08,-1.77636e-15,-1,2.98023e-08,1.5099e-14,1,-2.98023e-08,1.5099e-14,1,-2.98023e-08,1.5099e-14,1,-2.98023e-08,1,3.27825e-07,5.66244e-07,1,3.27825e-07,5.66244e-07,1,3.27825e-07,5.66244e-07,-5.0664e-07,1.49012e-07,1,-5.0664e-07,1.49012e-07,1,-5.0664e-07,1.49012e-07,1,-1,-1.19209e-07,-2.08616e-07,-1,-1.19209e-07,-2.08616e-07,-1,-1.19209e-07,-2.08616e-07,2.38419e-07,1.78814e-07,-1,2.38419e-07,1.78814e-07,-1,2.38419e-07,1.78814e-07,-1],
                "itemSize":3,
                "type":"Float32Array"
            },
            "position":{
                "array":[1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,0.999999,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,0.999999,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,0.999999,1,1,1,1,-1,0.999999,1,1,1,-1,1,0.999999,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1],
                "itemSize":3,
                "type":"Float32Array"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have uploaded the JSON file to a server, and with a basic setup tried to load it into a scene:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="assets/js/three.js"></script>
        <script>

            /* Scene
             */
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
            var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add( cube );

            camera.position.z = 5;

            cube.rotation.x = 2;
            cube.rotation.y = 2;

            renderer.render(scene, camera);

            /* Load the JSON
             */
            var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

            loader.load(

                'https://www.example.com/blender-cube.json',

                function ( geometry, materials ) {

                    var material = materials[ 0 ];
                    var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

                    scene.add( object );

                }
            );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

With above code, I get the green cube extracted from an example page <sup>[⇗](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/Creating-a-scene)</sup>, but when reaching to the `Load the JSON` portion <sup>[⇗](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/JSONLoader)</sup>, the following error is displayed on the browser console:

> TypeError: vertices is undefined
>   three.js:33296.5

The mentioned error line is inside the `parseModel( json, geometry )` function.

Seems to me that the three.js exporter for Blender is missing something when generating the JSON file. The function `parseModel()` is expecting a `vertices` property not present on the generated JSON file.

A working snippet, with a little tweak to the `Load the JSON` portion, to have the JSON file in a JavaScript variable:

```js
/* Scene
 */
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0x00ff00
});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

camera.position.z = 5;

cube.rotation.x = 2;
cube.rotation.y = 2;

renderer.render(scene, camera);

/* Load the JSON
 */
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

var blenderCubeObject = {
  "metadata": {
    "generator": "io_three",
    "normal": 36,
    "position": 36,
    "version": 3,
    "type": "BufferGeometry"
  },
  "data": {
    "index": {
      "array": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
      "itemSize": 1,
      "type": "Uint16Array"
    },
    "attributes": {
      "normal": {
        "array": [-7.10543e-15, -1, 2.98023e-08, -7.10543e-15, -1, 2.98023e-08, -7.10543e-15, -1, 2.98023e-08, 7.10543e-15, 1, -2.98023e-08, 7.10543e-15, 1, -2.98023e-08, 7.10543e-15, 1, -2.98023e-08, 1, -2.38419e-07, 7.10543e-15, 1, -2.38419e-07, 7.10543e-15, 1, -2.38419e-07, 7.10543e-15, -5.96046e-08, -2.98023e-07, 1, -5.96046e-08, -2.98023e-07, 1, -5.96046e-08, -2.98023e-07, 1, -1, -1.49012e-07, -2.38419e-07, -1, -1.49012e-07, -2.38419e-07, -1, -1.49012e-07, -2.38419e-07, 2.38419e-07, 1.78814e-07, -1, 2.38419e-07, 1.78814e-07, -1, 2.38419e-07, 1.78814e-07, -1, -1.77636e-15, -1, 2.98023e-08, -1.77636e-15, -1, 2.98023e-08, -1.77636e-15, -1, 2.98023e-08, 1.5099e-14, 1, -2.98023e-08, 1.5099e-14, 1, -2.98023e-08, 1.5099e-14, 1, -2.98023e-08, 1, 3.27825e-07, 5.66244e-07, 1, 3.27825e-07, 5.66244e-07, 1, 3.27825e-07, 5.66244e-07, -5.0664e-07, 1.49012e-07, 1, -5.0664e-07, 1.49012e-07, 1, -5.0664e-07, 1.49012e-07, 1, -1, -1.19209e-07, -2.08616e-07, -1, -1.19209e-07, -2.08616e-07, -1, -1.19209e-07, -2.08616e-07, 2.38419e-07, 1.78814e-07, -1, 2.38419e-07, 1.78814e-07, -1, 2.38419e-07, 1.78814e-07, -1],
        "itemSize": 3,
        "type": "Float32Array"
      },
      "position": {
        "array": [1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 0.999999, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 0.999999, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 0.999999, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 0.999999, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 0.999999, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1],
        "itemSize": 3,
        "type": "Float32Array"
      }
    }
  }
};

var model = loader.parse(blenderCubeObject);

mesh = new THREE.Mesh(model.geometry, model.materials[0]);

scene.add(mesh);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/86/three.js"></script>
```

**Any clue to what is happening or what I'm doing wrong ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing the type in apply modifier to geometry as opposed to buffergeometry and see if that helps.

Comment: Solved the `vertices is undefined`, but generated a new error `model.materials is undefined` on the JavaScript code, where I try to access the index 0: `mesh = new THREE.Mesh(model.geometry, model.materials[0]);`. This last one, I've solved by ticking the "Face Materials" on the export settings. I am now without any errors but the object isn't displayed... a subject to another question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I usually select all of vertices, faces, normals and UV's and also select Face materials. I then create the mesh via new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MultiMaterial(materials));. This currently works for me. I can post a working json file if that helps? Cheers.

Comment: I will give it a try, following your instructions. Thank you.